# Insert into with select, with some values specified and the remainder copied by default

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL query, coming from PHP:

```
INSERT INTO $table (nid, type)
SELECT nid, '7890'
FROM $table
WHERE nid = 1234 AND type = 1234
```

It basically copies a row within a table (the name specified by the PHP value `$table`) but with a new value for 'type'. This works fine, however I'm running it in a big loop that goes over lots of tables, where they all have nid and type in common, but also with extra columns.

Is there a way of adding a "splat", if that's the right way of phrasing it, to the end. So I specify the nid and type, but every other value will also get copied within the same table. My initial thinking was `(nid, type, *) SELECT nid, '7890', *` or something to that degree, but obviously it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, an `INSERT` requires listing all columns individually. This is Drupal, I'm guessing?

Comment: You could generate the SQL dynamically looking at meta data views, but short of that you just got to type them all out.

Comment: The table `information_schema.columns` will have metadata on the tables in `$table` - you can use that to generate the SQL dynamically.

Comment: Indeed it is Drupal. Technically I can just do a select and then pipe it back in within PHP rather than in one SQL query, or I could do it manually. This way just seemed a bit more succinct. Nevermind if it's not possible though

Comment: Is accessing `information_schema.columns` a good idea btw? It sounds a bit hacky and gross